# Can children access Air New Zealand lounges if travelling with a Star Alliance Gold holder?

Tags: children, lounges, air-new-zealand

Air New Zealand has an [unusually generous lounge policy](https://www.airnewzealand.com.au/lounges) for the children of its own elite members:

> Children: A maximum of three children aged 3 to 17 years (inclusive), may access Air New Zealand Lounges on a complimentary basis, if they are travelling with an Airpoints Elite, Gold, Elite Partner or Koru member, subject to space availability.

Does this extend to Star Alliance Gold members on other airlines as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat surprisingly but sadly, the answer is **no**.

On first reading I thought "Elite Partner" referred to elite members of partner airlines, but it's actually a [weird Air NZ status](https://www.airnewzealand.com.au/elite-partner-benefits).  Star Alliance elite members only get the usual allowance of one guest, and only children under 2 are free.  You can, however, bring in paying guests at A$45/person (in Sydney, prices may vary elsewhere).

Source: Staff at the Air NZ lounge in Sydney.

Comment: YMMV: I once got my partner and our daughter into an LH lounge just by asking nicely. They can say no but they don't HAVE to say no.

Comment: @Hilmar I did the same with two kids once at the same lounge, which is one more reason I was surprised to find out that was apparently against policy.